# Need suggestion on wire size (AWG) for running brushed DC motors

Tags: dc-motor, brushed-dc-motor, awg

I am a beginner and working on building a 4-wheel unmanned ground vehicle. I bought four brushed DC motors from Pololu. According to the datasheet, the stall current is 4.9A. But the wires that come with the motors are 26AWG. From the AWG wire size chart, I understand that these wires are not good enough to run these motors. **Am I making any mistakes?** I have attached the link to the datasheet of these motors (page 49).

Pololu 25D motor datasheet - https://www.pololu.com/file/0J1829/pololu-25d-metal-gearmotors.pdf

AWG wire size chart from engineering toolbox - https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/wire-gauges-d_419.html

If the attached wires are not good, I will change them. According to the AWG wire chart, I think these wires from Amazon should work fine (**AWG 22 solid core**) [https://www.amazon.com/TUOFENG-Hookup-Wires-6-Different-Colored/dp/B07TX6BX47/ref=sr_1_6?crid=VZFPK56JQPY1&keywords=awg%2B22%2Bsolid&qid=1688233980&sprefix=awg%2B22%2Bsolid%2Caps%2C109&sr=8-6&th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07TX6BX47)

[image: Datasheet_Pololu_25D_Brushed_DC_motor]

Comment: What current is your power supply capable of delivering? Maybe use an active current limit circuit per motor to protect it from overheating (after all you are likely to be controlling the motors individually and adding current limiting is fairly easy).

Comment: If the motor's correctly geared, it'll run far below the stall current most of the time, and a short run of 26awg would be fine in practice. Moments at stall current won't do damage; a long term stall will heat the wire.

Comment: Wires that might flex after installation should be stranded, not solid. A steering mechanism or maintenance could cause flexing.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.